# Is it possible to use refiners created in site collection A into site collection B

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have two site collection A and B.

I have created two refiners **Refiner1_A** and **Refiner2_A** in SiteCollection A.

My requirement is to use **Refiner1_A** and **Refiner2_A** in site collection B.

*Note:* I am able to get results from **SiteCollection A** into **SiteCollection B**

Answer (score 0):

No, though you can export the configuration from Site Collection A and import the configuration to site collection B. Site Settings | Search Configuration Export/Import. The only way to make the "global" is to define them at the SSA/ Tenant level.